# Serverless framework, have same API be available on two different domains

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless

I am trying to serve lambda developed using serverless framework using two different custom domain names.

I added the following custom resources to my serverless.yml file:

```
 Resources:
    APIDomain1:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
      Properties:
        RegionalCertificateArn: !ImportValue TF-Cert
        DomainName: 'api.domain1.com'
        EndpointConfiguration:
          Types:
            - REGIONAL
    APIDomain2:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
      Properties:
        RegionalCertificateArn: !ImportValue TF-Cert
        DomainName: 'api.domain2.com'
        EndpointConfiguration:
          Types:
            - REGIONAL
    APIBasePathMapping1:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
      DependsOn: APIDomainMapping
      Properties:
        DomainName: 'api.domain1.com'
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        Stage: ${self:provider.stage}
    APIBasePathMapping2:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
      DependsOn: APIDomainMapping
      Properties:
        DomainName:  'api.domain2.com'
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        Stage: ${self:provider.stage}
```

Unfortunately,  when I try to deploy this stack I get this error message

```
APIBasePathMapping1 - api.domain1.com|(none) already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:XXXXXXXX
```

I also see a corresponding event in the AWS Cloudformation console.  As a result stack creating fails and I have neither domain mapped to the rest API

However, if I remove one of the `AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping` from the `serverless.yml` deploy the stack and then manually add the domain mapping everything works as I want it to.

Is this a problem with serverless framework or cloudformation?  Am I doing something wrong?